# How to refresh or reset the app in phonegap+jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app in which user needs to set some parameters on settings page and then the user  moves the slider (which is on home page of app) and the results are displayed on home page.
But after performing the calculation, when i press the home button of iPhone simulator and again open the app.It is displaying the same selected settings and everything.
How should i refresh it or reset everything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind an event handler to the `pause` or `resume` events that PhoneGap exposes. Documentation can be found here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#Events

> **Resume**
>
> This is an event that fires when a PhoneGap application is retrieved
>   from the background.

```
function onResume() {
    //run code to reset your app here
}

document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```

Comment: that's what I'm looking for.code to reset the app.like if i would shutdown and again open the app, it should start from fresh.

Comment: I have tried to use it but by testing it with just an alert but it never seems to work for me :( any idea why ?? I used it like this document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
  function onResume() {
      alert('resumed');
  }
in the head

Comment: @colourtheweb You may need to place the function declaration before the event listener hook so it's a known value. Not really sure about that though.

Comment: @Jasper thanks for replying but I did tried that too but no help!!